# question on get; set;

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I would like to set a modified flag when ever I change one of the class properties as shown below

```
public bool Modified { get; set; }
public bool Enabled { get; set { Modified = true; } }
```

problem is I have an error and the compiler is asking me to declare a body for the get;
I would rather not have to declare a separate private variable, is there another way to do this.

c#, ,net-2

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  If you want an explicit setter, you can't use an automatic getter.  So you must have something like:

```
private bool _Enabled;
public bool Modified { get; set; }
public bool Enabled
{
    get 
    {
        return _Enabled;
    }
    set 
    {
        _Enabled = value; 
        Modified = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could probably only set `Modified` to be `true` in the setter if `_Enabled != value`.

Comment: @Jason, I just kept it like the question.  You may be right, depending on the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. C# does not allow you to specify a body for one or the other of `get` or `set` but have the other implemented automatically. If you need to do this, you need a manual property with a backing field.

Note that you want something like this:

```
public bool Modified { get; set; }

private bool enabled;
public bool Enabled {
    get { return this.enabled; }
    set {
        if(this.enabled != value) {
            this.enabled = value;
            this.Modified = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write the getter and setter for Enabled in full:

```
public bool Modified { get; set; }

private bool enabled;

public bool Enabled
{
    get { return enabled; }

    set
    {
        if (enabled != value)
        {
            Modified = true;
            enabled = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since a automatic generated member will be created for `get; set;` property then you cant declare one of them otherwise you have to set them by your own